# how to POST comment to wordpress site

Tags: iphone, ios, wordpress, post

Encountered a problem on posting comment back to a comment box.
post not showing up, there is no error or whatsoever to check.

EDIT: Correct Answer

```
-(void)postToBoard
{      
  NSString *post = @"author=Jos&email=mail@domain.com.au&url=&comment=score+99.&submit=Post+Comment&comment_post_ID=1&comment_post_ID=1&comment_parent=0";

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSString *URLString = @"http://site.com.au/?p=1";
    NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];    

    [request setURL:postURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//[request setValue:@"wp-comments-post.php" forHTTPHeaderField:@"HTTP/1.1"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

    //self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    self.postConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line looks wrong:

```
[request setValue:@"wp-comments-post.php" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

It should be:

```
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

I'm not sure what you're supposed to do with "wp-comments-post.php", should that perhaps be in the URL instead?